# How do I get rid off \u0083\u0092airs pattern in?

Tags: r

I have a text that I am working with, however, even after deleting Unicode's and other cleaning steps, I am still left with couple of strings like this:

```
\u0083\u0092airs,
\u0083\u0092ect,
\u0083\u0092ected,
\u0083\u0092ecting,
\u0083\u0092ective,
\u0083\u0092ectiveapproaches,
\u0083\u0092ectiveclimate,
\u0083\u0092ectively,
```

Can somebody help me with regular expression or any another way to get rid of them?

Comment: You could generally remove those Unicode characters without problems unless you rely on them for something specific like a delimiter or a subsequent step needs them. `F'`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
iconv(string, from = "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
```